# JPA/Hibernate: Update Parent column value before inserting child column value

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

This is my scenario. I have a Parent table `Files_Info` and a child table `Files_Versions`.

```
create table files_info(
   id bigint primary key, 
   name varchar(255) not null, 
   description varchar(255) not null, 
   last_modified TIMESTAMP, 
   latest_version integer default 0 not null
);

create table files_versions(
   id bigint primary key,
   file_id bigint references files_info(id), 
   version integer not null, 
   location text not null, 
   created TIMESTAMP, 
   unique(file_id, version)
);
```

This is mainly to track a file and its various versions. When the user initiates a new file creation (not yet uploaded any version of the file), an entry is made to the `files_info` table with basic info like name, description. The latest_version will be 0 initially.

Then when the user uploads the first version, an entry is created in the `files_versions` table for that file_id and the version 
value is set as parent's `latest_version` + 1. Parent's `latest_version` is now set to 1.

The user can also upload an initial version of the file when he/she initiates a new file creation. In that case, parent record 
will be created with latest_version as 1 and also the corresponding version 1 child record.

I do not know how to design this using JPA / Hibernate.

I wrote my Entity and Repository classes and the save methods seem to work independently. But I do not know how to do the simultaneously `latest_version` updates.

Can this be done using JPA / Hibernate? Or should it be a database trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger is a valid option, but It can be done using JPA/Hibernate.

I'll suggest to use `@PrePersist` annotation on some method defined at the `files_versions` entity ... This method will be called by JPA when you execute: `EntityManager.persist(FileVersion);` and it can be use to update entity's derivative attributes ... In your case, will be the sum of the file last_version + 1 ... Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "files_info")
public class FileInfo {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = files_versions)
public class FileVersion {
    ... //some attributes
    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_id")
    private FileInfo fileInfo;

    ... //some getters and setters

    @PrePersist
    private void setupVersion() {
        // fileInfo should be set before of calling persist()!
        // fileInfo should increase its lastest Version before of calling persist()!
        this.version = this.fileInfo.getLastVersion();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I think that PrePersist should work. I already have a method annotated with PrePersist where I update the last modified timestamp. It didn't strike for me.